# Reputation graph suggests you've been a member for longer than you are

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, new-users, reputation-graph

I joined a [new site](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/) two days ago. When I look at the reputation graph on my profile, it looks like I've been a member for a couple of weeks already:

[image: screenshot of reputation graph]

Wouldn't it be better to limit the graph from the moment you joined the site? That would mean it would only show one dot for an account created today, but I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: Alternative option is to show reputation as 0 before joining, since once you join your reputation can't be lower then 1.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ or ever better, leave the date but hide the graph until the actual joining date.

Comment: @Shadow hide the graph may be considered same as 0 rep, if the lowest value on graph is set to 1 :)