# When focusing the search box in a private beta, hints fail to load, causing a popup with the login page

Tags: bug, status-review, search, private-beta, popups

I just followed by [a link](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=beta&returnurl=%2F) from [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389263/339911) here and got this funny behavior after clicking on the search bar:

> [image]

The entire site opened in a new popup window!

Comment: It's the login page, since the search hints page requires you to be logged in to the site, aka join it. I'm pretty sure the bug always existed, and nobody noticed until now. Though for many years, users couldn't even view private beta before joining.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard what? I was never asked to login to use searchbar! Just open any site in private mode and check by self.

Comment: It's technical issue. Click the search bar here, and you get the search tips. Those are loaded from [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search/hints) with simple AJAX. However, for some reason, on private beta, that path is blocked for visitors who have not joined, hence it throws error that cause the browser to load the login page instead, and that's the bug that needs to be fixed. (Remove the restriction over the `/search/hints` path.)

Comment: I was able to easily duplicate this by opening the site in a window where I'm not logged in (e.g. private window, alternate browser profile/person, etc.). The issue is that when not logged in with an account that has a profile on the site, the GET to `https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/search/hints` returns a 302 response redirecting the request to `/users/login?ssrc=beta&returnurl=%2fsearch%2fhints`, which, unsurprisingly, returns the login page. The GET was to get the HTML content for the search help popup, so the HTML content for the login page is used for the popup. Definitely a bug.